# use mockjax proxy, won't execute to done callback

Tags: javascript, ajax, mocking

I use mockjax 1.6.1 to mock ajax and mock the response . when I use proxy setting,it won't execute the success call back. code shows below:

```
$.mockjax({
  url : "rest/getAvailableSysems",
  proxy : 'resources/scripts/cache/mocks/systems-mock.json'
});
$.ajax({
  url : "rest/getAvailableSysems",
  success : function(data) {  // do something
   };   // won't execute here
});
```

if I use reponseText, then the callback will be executed, why?
code show below

```
$.mockjax({
  url : "rest/getAvailableSysems",
  responseText: [{'name1':'value1'},{'name2':'value2'},{'name3':'value3'}]
});
$.ajax({
  url : "rest/getAvailableSysems",
  success : function(data) {  // do something
  };   // execute here
});
```

thanks in advance